# Placeholder and label getting overlapped when using custom template in Angular formly

Tags: angular-material, angular-formly

Placeholder and label are getting overlapped if default value is not set in model for a field. This issue is coming when using custom template in Angular formly. Is it the CSS issue. I tried setting mat-form-field but still no help.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formly-demo

Answer (score 0):

For material UI you'll need to import `FieldType` from `@ngx-formly/material`,
the next missing part is importing `MatInputModule`.

here is working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formly-demo-hpha5n